# Listing a cell as a variable after finding the next empty one

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I want Excel to find the next empty cell in Column J on the sheet named Summary. I want that cell to be a variable named PipeSize. I then want to go to a sheet that is a variable NewName and select cell C60 and put whatever is inputted into the cell PipeSize into cell C60. This is my code.

```
Sheets("Summary").Select
Set PipeSize = Range("J" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select


Sheets(Newname).Select
Range("C60").Select
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=PipeSize"
```

The variable Newname is properly created and is not causing the problem. It is the row Set PipeSize that is causing the problem. Thank you!

Comment: `.Formula = "=Summary!" & PipeSize.Address`

Comment: Also get rid of the `.Select` after `Offset(1)`.

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: `Row.Count` ---> `Rows.Count`